# why `lodash.map(['A'], String.prototype.toLowerCase.call)` does not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, callback, lodash

If I want get an array of strings converted to lowercase, this seems like the normal thing to do:

```
lodash = require('lodash')
lodash.map(['A', 'B'], String.prototype.toLowerCase.call)

TypeError: object is not a function
    at Function.map (/Users/alejandro.carrasco/repos/cap-proxy/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3508:27)
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

I've dug a little bit in the code and it seems that the problem is produced by the `createCallback` wrapping the passed function used inside `map`:

```
lodash.createCallback(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call)('A')

TypeError: object is not a function
    at repl:1:58
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

But I don't really understand what's going on there...

I know that it works if I pass a callback like this:

```
function(x) {return x.toLowerCase()}
```

but the curiosity is killing me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why

The same reason `['A', 'B'].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call)` is not working — it effectively uses `Function.prototype.call.call(thisArg, currentValue)` as an iterator which throws `TypeError: object is not a function` because your `thisArg` is global context (`process`) instead of `String.prototype.toLowerCase`.

## How

```js
// You expect this to be your iterator:
String.prototype.toLowerCase.call('A');

// Instead, you got this:
String.prototype.toLowerCase.call.call(thisArg, 'A');
```

Since `thisArg` is bound to `process` in your example, line above is pretty much the same as:
`process()` with `this` bound to `'A'`.

```js
// The "correct" invocation "should" be:
String.prototype.toLowerCase.call.call(String.prototype.toLowerCase, 'A');
```

## Fix

You can fix it by passing "correct" `thisArg`. The following ones work, but such `map`s do not look better than `function(x) {return x.toLowerCase()}` to me:

```js
['A'].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call, String.prototype.toLowerCase);
['A'].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));
['A'].map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.toLowerCase);
['A'].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));
```

**upd** With ES2015 and [transpilers](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20array%20%3D%20'UPPERCASE'.split('')%3B%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20array.map(letter%20%3D%3E%20letter.toLowerCase())%3B) for it being pretty mature nowadays, I'd prefer the following:

```js
['A'].map(letter => letter.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: well spotted! being that a `call.call` references the same function and not a *second degree unbounded* function is what I missed :)

Answer (score 3):

When you pass `String.prototype.toLowerCase.call` as the iterator function, you're really just passing the `call` function, without a context.

The context of the `call` function is usually the function which should be called. In this case it seems like the context is set to some object (global object?), and therefore you get the error `object is not a function`.

A possible solution is to bind the context of `Function.call` to `String.prototype.toLowerCase`, like so:

```
_.map(['A', 'B'], Function.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
_.map(['A', 'B'], Function.call.bind("".toLowerCase));
```

After some more testing I found that the following code works with underscore but not with Lo-Dash, at least in the browser:

```
_.map(['A', 'B'], Function.call, "".toLowerCase);
```